# Generate fake data with mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, faker

I'm using mongoose schemas at application level in combination with mongodb. For testing, I want to fill my mongodb with fake data. The library *mongoose-faker* does not seem to be automatic. I know there are fakers for JSON-Schema, but I don't want to maintain to types of Schemas.

Is it possible to generate fake data *automaticaly*?

Greetings

Daniel

Edit: I'll try to generate a JSON-Schema from my Mongoose-Schema. I can test this on monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mongoose-Schema can be transformed into an JSON-Schema with the module `mongoose-schema-jsonschema`. Fake data can be generated with the module `json-schema-faker`.

It's nice to know, that the transformation can only transform standard mongoose types to JSON-Schema. Also the faker seems to have problems with generating required fields if they are in an array of objects.

But in general this solution works.